# What is the purpose of the -char parameter in SQL Explorer?

Tags: openedge, progress-db

I recently started using Progress OpenEdge and am confused about the purpose of the -char parameter to the sqlexp (SQL Explorer) command from Progress's command line utility, Proenv.

I have looked at the documentation [here](https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dmsdv%2Fconnecting-using-sql-explorer.html%23wwID0EAKAK), but apparently Progress didn't feel that parameter should be documented. I've also looked in the Progress Knowledge Base but can't find an actual definition for the -char parameter.

For example, I see no difference between the commands `sqlexp -char -db C:\pathtomydb\mydb.db -H 127.0.0.1 -S 2500 -user jmoor -password ***` and `sqlexp -db C:\pathtomydb\mydb.db -H 127.0.0.1 -S 2500 -user jmoor -password ***`

Both commands seems to do the exact same thing. Even if I run an actual SQL command such as `SELECT * FROM PUB.CUSTOMER WHERE "Cust-id" = 15;` using the -command parameter, the -char parameter seems to make no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Help says the following but I can't see any way to configure it. I checked sqlexp.bat and it is not using GUI class in any manner. Looks like it is an overlook. You can ignore it.

```
Usage:  sqlexp [-modeoptions] [-connectoptions] [-generaloptions]

where mode options include:
     -char               Optional argument.  Default is GUI mode.
```

Answer (score 3):

It is obsolete since 10.1A, see https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P92359